# Php Resizing with image gd not displaying the image but does the resizing

Tags: php, image, gd

I have made a lot of search on this subject and still ...
I have a php code to resize images with library Gd but the trouble is that after resizing it does not display the image.
This is the code

File name resize.php

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP function to resize an image maintaining aspect ratio
 * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2008/10/resize-images-using-phpgd-library.html
 *
 * Creates a resized (e.g. thumbnail, small, medium, large)
 * version of an image file and saves it as another file
 */

define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH', 150);
define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT', 150);

function generate_image_thumbnail($source_image_path, $thumbnail_image_path)
{
    list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) = getimagesize($source_image_path);
    switch ($source_image_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image_path);
            break;
    }
    if ($source_gd_image === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $source_aspect_ratio = $source_image_width / $source_image_height;
    $thumbnail_aspect_ratio = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
    if ($source_image_width <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH && $source_image_height <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT) {
        $thumbnail_image_width = $source_image_width;
        $thumbnail_image_height = $source_image_height;
    } elseif ($thumbnail_aspect_ratio > $source_aspect_ratio) {
        $thumbnail_image_width = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT * $source_aspect_ratio);
        $thumbnail_image_height = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
    } else {
        $thumbnail_image_width = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH;
        $thumbnail_image_height = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / $source_aspect_ratio);
    }
    $thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height);
    imagejpeg($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 90);
    imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail_gd_image);
    return true;
}

generate_image_thumbnail('sql/max.jpg', 'sql/thumbnail_image_width_max.jpg');
?>
```

And in index.php i did something like this

```
<img src="resize.php"/>
```

The trouble is that it resizes the image but it does not display it when i do `<img src="resize.php"/>` , yet the image exist as in `<img src="sql/thumbnail_image_width_max.jpg"/>` exists. But without doing `<img src="resize.php"/>`  i do not even know how to resize the image so that i may display it directly maybe with `<img src="sql/thumbnail_image_width_max.jpg"/>` or display it directly with `<img src="resize.php"/>.`

Thanks for helping. And hope my question will not be flag with minus again this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me help you here.
that function work fine, so, i think that your problem is in the `index.php`.
in that file add:

```
include("resize.php"); //to include the function.
```

then call the function and check if work fine.

```
$result=generate_image_thumbnail('sql/max.jpg', 'sql/thumbnail_image_width_max.jpg');

if($result)
echo '<img src="sql/thumbnail_image_width_max.jpg"/>';
else
echo "error in image function";
```